# Photos and Animated .gif disappear in Open Office Impress

Tags: openoffice, presentations, openoffice-impress

I use Open Office on Windows 8.

When I create Presentation using Impress, I insert photos and animated .gifs.

However, if I move that Impress presentation, or delete the referring photos and animated gifs, all the multimedia disappears from Impress.

I even emailed myself a copy of the Impress presentation and all the photos and animations have disappeared.

How on Earth do I fix this?

I have an online presentation to give in about a week, and I wish to give a copy of the Impress presentation to viewers, which includes the animations, rather than exporting to static .pdf.

Please help!!!!!

Comment: When you say you email them to yourself, are you viewing them on a different computer or they don't even show up on the same computer?

Comment: @MC10 Both. When I email them to myself and open on different computer, the graphics in the presentation disappear. And in the original computer, if I delete the original clipart folder, the graphics in the presentation disappear.

Comment: Make sure the images are [embedded, not linked](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2008/05/how-to-make-sur.html).

Comment: @MC10 Gonna try this

Comment: @MC10 Thank you so much, it works!

Comment: Good to hear, glad the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the [pictures linked, instead of embedded](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2008/05/how-to-make-sur.html). When you insert them, make sure the **Link** checkbox is not ticked. If they are linked, you will still need the source file or they will disappear as you said. If you **embed** them, they no longer need the source files.

[image: Linked]
[image: Linked 2]

If you have already added them and they are linked, don't worry. There is a way to remove the links. Go to the **Edit** menu and then **Links...**.

[image: Edit, Links]

If links exist, you can select **Break Link**, and that will remove the link and embed your image.

[image: Break Link]

Images from source linked above: http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2008/05/how-to-make-sur.html