# How to embed (not insert) MP3 in OpenOffice Impress

Tags: mp3, openoffice, slideshow, openoffice-impress, embedding

My question is similar to this, [Photos and Animated .gif disappear in Open Office Impress](https://superuser.com/questions/959117/photos-and-animated-gif-disappear-in-open-office-impress)

But unfortunately when I go to Edit, the Links option is greyed out.

Is there another way to embed mp3 files?

I need to email the slides to the attendees and would like the mp3 to be embedded.

[image]

I also tried [applying slide transition to embed](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080516165803AAfKBGz), but all it does is allows me to loop the mp3.

[image]

Plz tell how to embed the mp3!!!!!

I also saved as .ppt but issue persists!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but any ideas on how to fix this?