# Dancing .gif in slideshow "smears" the image in OpenOffice Impress

Tags: animated-gif, openoffice-impress

I'm creating slides which includes a dancing .gif

[image]

Unfortunately when I play the slideshow, it leaves an impression of the image in the background, like this

[image]

How to fix this???

This .gif render properly in SlideShow mode

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with all motion GIFs or just this dancing one in particular?

Comment: Also, what is OpenOffice Libre? I could have sworn that OpenOffice and LibreOffice are two distinct applications.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I changed the title, it's OpenOffice Impress. Other motion .gifs are fine, will add to question.

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with the first GIF because the white space is actually alpha-transparency; might be a bug with OpenOffice's rendering engine not clearing the previous frame and showing the new frame on top of it. I would recommend seeing if you can edit the GIF to hard-code a white background to each frame so that OpenOffice cannot suffer from the transparency side-effect. If you change the background color of your slide to yellow then this effect will become more obvious.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I saved as .ppt and now it works!

Comment: Nice! Good luck with the rest of the presentation!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you. Actually, I am troubleshooting one more issue, perhaps you may have some ideas, http://superuser.com/questions/961734/how-to-embed-not-insert-mp3-in-openoffice-impress